# Dell inspiron 5567 laptop, Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Long term boot problem with weird patterns

Tags: boot, dell, battery, freeze

I will try put all the details i have collected since the beginning of the issue so you have clear picture of what is going on.

---

At july, i moved to my new place and this was the first time i had some issues. At that point, my **laptop's battery was ruined** so i had always it always plugged in. The case was, while my laptop was running it **suddenly started freezing** with only to shut it down, the cold shut-down button. **I tried fresh install of Ubuntu but nothing**.

---

Then i decided to go to a **hardware tech guy**. He told me he found nothing wrong with laptop. As soon as i came home the laptop crushes within the first minutes. I run some BIOS diagnostics and the result was **the fan was not working**. I call the guy and he tells me that most probably that was his fault and messed up something in the procedure. Anyway fan is properly put, and the problem tends to appear more sporadically.

---

Fast forward some weeks, it seems that, due to the fact that the house is old, we have some **problems with the voltage in our rooms** (me and my roommate) because the general switch was going down. The next day after the incident with the general switch, my laptop wont open. It is stuck [screen of laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkir0.jpg) here. I couldn't figure out why this was happening but i assumed that it had to do with the battery.

---

Crucial point to my not understanding whats going on is that the next day **i move to my home town, and then i put my battery out, i plug my laptop and it is working like charm**. Although, **when i move back to my house, my laptop won't open even without battery**. I am really desperate, **i go buy a new battery and i start having the feeling that voltage has something to do with it**. **I wear the new battery to my laptop, and decide to charge it at the kitchen**, because at old houses kitchens used to have better greater current. Laptop opens. I close it, **put it back to my room. Doesn't open with or without charger**.

---

Since then, its like a coin flip. I know for sure that my laptop will boot if it is plugged in at the kitchen. When it is in my room, most of the times will not boot.I really don't know what to do. Any suggestion will be more than welcome! Thank you for your time reading this.

Comment: So, where are the details? It is clearly not the parts in bold, as they seem to be not particularly illuminating or relevant, but rather arbitrary.

Comment: Even perfectly good electronics will misbehave (ie. *work outside of design intentions*) if fed bad power.  In theory the power supply (PSU) should deal with most minor power issues, but it's not magical. You mention powering off with power button; was SysRq key combinations not working? as that's far safer & provides useful clues.

Comment: @guiverc I tried all possible SysRq key combinations but none worked. What puzzles me most is, since i replaced my battery, why my laptop won't boot without charger, even when the battery is charged.

Comment: @mikewhatever From my point of view those are the details cause this is all i have noticed. What more would be helpful? What would provide more information?

Comment: Let's reset the Power Manager. Shutdown your computer. Hold down the POWER button for ~20-30 seconds. Reboot and retest. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Followed the instructions. First couple of times the laptop booted  unplugged without any problem. I hope it lasts. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

Reset the Power Manager. Shutdown your computer. Hold down the POWER button for ~20-30 seconds. Reboot and retest.

Check that the AC power supply is properly charging the battery when plugged into AC.

Test your AC circuits with a cheap AC plug-in wall socket tester from your local hardware store, or Amazon. It'll show incorrectly wired sockets, or bad grounds.

[https://www.amazon.com/Bastex-Tester-Receptacle-Indications-Electric/dp/B071FVB35Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071FVB35Q)

**Update #1:**

*Followed the instructions. First couple of times the laptop booted unplugged without any problem. I hope it lasts.*